# Looping in Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to Access and VBA and I've been searching how to do for loops in VBA. I'm drawing 8 boxes on a report and everything is looking good but I would like to know if I can use looping to create the code below to shorten it up:

```
  Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)

  Dim X1 As Single, Y1 As Single
  Dim X2 As Single, Y2 As Single
  Dim Color As Long
  '************************************
  Dim page_start_left_1 As Integer
  Dim page_start_top_1 As Integer
  Dim page_end_left_1 As Integer
  Dim page_end_top_1 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Width_1 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Height_1 As Integer
  '****
  Dim page_start_left_2 As Integer
  Dim page_start_top_2 As Integer
  Dim page_end_left_2 As Integer
  Dim page_end_top_2 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Width_2 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Height_2 As Integer
  '****
  Dim page_start_left_3 As Integer
  Dim page_start_top_3 As Integer
  Dim page_end_left_3 As Integer
  Dim page_end_top_3 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Width_3 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Height_3 As Integer
  '****
  Dim page_start_left_4 As Integer
  Dim page_start_top_4 As Integer
  Dim page_end_left_4 As Integer
  Dim page_end_top_4 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Width_4 As Integer
  Dim page_end_Height_4 As Integer
  '************************************
  ' Set to 1st question on page 1
  page_start_left_1 = Me!Q1text.Left
  page_start_top_1 = Me!Q1text.Top
  ' Set to last question on page 1
  page_end_left_1 = Me!Q7text.Left
  page_end_top_1 = Me!Q7text.Top
  page_end_Width_1 = Me!Q7text.Width
  page_end_Height_1 = Me!Q7text.Height
  ' Set to 1st question on page 2
  page_start_left_2 = Me!Q8text.Left
  page_start_top_2 = Me!Q8text.Top
  ' Set to last question on page 2
  page_end_left_2 = Me!Q27text.Left
  page_end_top_2 = Me!Q27text.Top
  page_end_Width_2 = Me!Q27text.Width
  page_end_Height_2 = Me!Q27text.Height
  ' Set to 1st question on page 3
  page_start_left_3 = Me!Q28text.Left
  page_start_top_3 = Me!Q8text.Top
  ' Set to last question on page 3
  page_end_left_3 = Me!QBP3text.Left
  page_end_top_3 = Me!QBP3text.Top
  page_end_Width_3 = Me!QBP3text.Width
  page_end_Height_3 = Me!QBP3text.Height
  ' Set to 1st question on page 4
  page_start_left_4 = Me!QADHD1text.Left
  page_start_top_4 = Me!QADHD1text.Top
  ' Set to last question on page 4
  page_end_left_4 = Me!QCoOccur4text.Left
  page_end_top_4 = Me!QCoOccur4text.Top
  page_end_Width_4 = Me!QCoOccur4text.Width
  page_end_Height_4 = Me!QCoOccur4text.Height
  '************************************************* *******************
  '1st Page left box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_1 + 7000
  Y1 = page_start_top_1 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_1 + page_end_Width_1 + 2900
  Y2 = page_end_top_1 + page_end_Height_1
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B
  '1st Page right box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_1 + 10130
  Y1 = page_start_top_1 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_1 + page_end_Width_1 + 5460
  Y2 = page_end_top_1 + page_end_Height_1
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B

  '************************************************* *******************
  '2st Page left box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_2 + 7000
  Y1 = page_start_top_2 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_2 + page_end_Width_2 + 2900
  Y2 = page_end_top_2 + page_end_Height_2
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B
  '2st Page right box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_2 + 10130
  Y1 = page_start_top_2 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_2 + page_end_Width_2 + 5460
  Y2 = page_end_top_2 + page_end_Height_2
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B
  '************************************************* *******************
  '3rd Page left box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_3 + 7000
  Y1 = page_start_top_3 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_3 + page_end_Width_3 + 2900
  Y2 = page_end_top_3 + page_end_Height_3
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B
  '3rd Page right box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_3 + 10130
  Y1 = page_start_top_3 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_3 + page_end_Width_3 + 5460
  Y2 = page_end_top_3 + page_end_Height_3
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B

  '*********************************************************************
  '4th Page left box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_4 + 7000
  Y1 = page_start_top_4 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_4 + page_end_Width_4 + 2900
  Y2 = page_end_top_4 + page_end_Height_4
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B
  '4th Page right box
  ' X and Y coordinates for the top left corner of the box.
  X1 = page_start_left_4 + 10130
  Y1 = page_start_top_4 - 100
  ' X and Y coordinates for the bottom right corner of the box.
  X2 = page_end_left_4 + page_end_Width_4 + 5460
  Y2 = page_end_top_4 + page_end_Height_4
  Me.DrawWidth = 3 ' Width of the line (in pixels).
  Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Use black line color.
  ' Draw the rectangle with the Line method.
  Me.Line (X1, Y1)-(X2, Y2), Color, B

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrays:

```
Dim page_start_left(8) As Integer
Dim Q(8) as string
Q(1) = "Q1text"
Q(2) = "Q7text"
...
For I = 1 to 8
  page_start_left(I).Left = me.controls(Q(I)).Left
  ...
next I
```

A more advanced method is to save all the names & other variables in a table, then just read that table in a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom this worked and thank you Joseph for your help

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for "shortening up" the code with a loop is to use an array to store this information, and then perform the calculations with an equation to generate/store the values.

Here is some 'almost' code - insert values or declarations for X, Y, and formulas.

```
Dim boxInfo(X, Y) As Short
For i As Integer = 0 To X 
   boxInfo(i,0) = formula0
   boxInfo(i,1) = formula1
   .
   .
   .
   boxInfo(i,Y) = formulaY
Next
```

You can replace the `X` with the number of boxes you've defined, and `Y` with the number of variables you've defined.

The idea here is that the formulas are some function of `i` which is not always possible in the context of screen display.  When I run into such situations, I do create the loop and then itemize another code block that is more clearly commented and maintainable where each assignment is explicitly defined.

Comment: I'm trying your code. It doesn't seem to be working. I blaming it on me like I said I'm new to VBA

Comment: Try this simpler example:
`Dim boxInfo(1, 1) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To 1 
   boxInfo(i,0) = 1 + i
   boxInfo(i,1) = 2 * i
Next`

To be sure the assignments are working, you can always do a `msgbox boxInfo(0,0)` at the end.